# How to extract columns and rows from a DataSet in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, dataset, comparison

****How can I compare the quantity of the UnitsInStock to the quantity the user wants to purchase?****

Here I have a query to my SQL database for the list of columns put into a DataSet. The "where" clause is the item I am browsing currently, extracting all the current information about this product.

**I tried to use get the data out into data columns, then I would now need to compare that with the int, quantity.**

```
        string selectionString =
        "SELECT Products.ProductID, " +
            "Products.ProductName, Categories.CategoryName, " +
            "Suppliers.CompanyName, Products.QuantityPerUnit," +
            "Products.UnitPrice, Products.UnitsInStock " +    
            "FROM Suppliers INNER JOIN (Categories  " +
            "INNER JOIN Products ON  " +
            "Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID)  " +
            "ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID " +
            "WHERE Products.ProductID = " +
            int.Parse(Session["Current Item"].ToString());

DataSet ds = new DataSet();//this is the dataset that keeps my columns and rows.
```

Then I have a loop to assign all columns except for the last, which is UnitsInStock, towards text boxes. **The value that I need to work with is an int, quantity.**

Depending on the item that the user opens up, each item's stock will be different. So the item that I open up, I want to know how I can compare the variable quantity, decided by the user, to the quantity number that I have extracted from the DataSet.

The index of the UnitsInStock column is **6**. Don't worry about QuantityPerUnit, it is nothing.

Here is code that takes ProductName, CatergoryName, CompanyName, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, and *UnitsInStock*, so you can see how the dataset is used.

```
 if (ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count != 0 &&
        ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
    {

        for (int index = 0; index < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; index++)/// count -1, explain
        {
            labelArray[index].Text = ds.Tables[0].Columns[index].ColumnName;//named constant
            if (index == 5) // The price field
            {

                textBoxArray[index].Text = ((Decimal)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][index]).ToString("F");
            }
            else
                textBoxArray[index].Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][index].ToString();
```

So, how can I compare the quantity retrieved by the database to the quantity the user wants to purchase, gathered from a textbox.

Comment: are you saying that there is a column for each item's row that contains qty?

Comment: There is a columns for ProductName, CatergoryName, CompanyName, QuantityPerUnit, UnitPrice, and UnitsInStock. UnitsInstock is the 6th column

Comment: where are you storing Quantity given by user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to compare them in your existing code would be another `if (index ==` statement in your `for` loop:

```
if (index == 6)
{
    int qtyUserWants = int.Parse(qtyUserWantsTextbox.Text);
    int qtyInStock = (int)ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][index];

    if (qtyUserWants >  qtyInStock)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to filter rows for the Quantity given by user. 
Following code selects only those rows which contains UnitsInStock equal to Quantity given by user.

I am assuming that Quantity given by user is stored in txtQuantityGivenByUser Textbox.

```
var selectedRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("UnitsInStock = " + txtQuantityGivenByUser.Text);
```